# rspec / testing after_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails

I guess am not testing it the right way, but still I was wondering how to make sure a method call is triggered in an after_action.

Having the followings :

```
  class AbcdController < ApplicationController
    after_action :handle_after, only: [:receive]
    def receive
       …… do some stuff
    end

    private

    def handle_after
       MyModule.my_method(some_data)
    end
  end
```

Then I'd like to test it like so (in a request spec) :

```
post  '/abcd/receive.json', params: params
expect(MyModule).to receive(:my_method)
```

This test does not passes. What would be an other approach to make sure the `MyModule.method` is called when the url if reached ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `have_received`:

```
post  '/abcd/receive.json', params: params
expect(MyModule).to have_received(:my_method)
```

Comment: 2 years later and a lot of experience gained, this is indeed the best way

Answer (score 0):

That's basically the way to do it.

Maybe, when you want more integration approach, instead of checking if `MyModule` received `:my_method` test the effect of calling this Module. 
For example, if it was recording an event in the DB, check

```
expect {post '/abcd/receive.json'}.to change{ Event.count }.by(1)
```

You need to define borders when your testing stops, so you have to balance amount of mocking with deeply checking the behavior of your app.

Comment: I guess it should works ok for a standard rails model; the problem happens with a 'custom' module (given the example, `app/lib/my_module.rb`). Haven't tried but the problem might be the same with classes

Comment: But what is the problem exactly? What is happening, and what would you expect instead?

Comment: As described. when posting to the controller's url (/abcd/receive), then testing if the method has been called (the one method in the after action) the test shown does not passes

Comment: @Ben I've read your question like 10 times - you didn't actually say that the expectation failed. What you're asking for is `another approach`. Please update your question, and also paste the rspec output.

Comment: indeed, sorry for that

Comment: Also - you example should totally work, so I'm really interested in what you see in the console.